# How to prevent different user types to view each other dashboard in django

Tags: python, django, django-views

I have a website with 3 user types, admin, instructor and students, I used login mixing to redirect each of them to their respective dashboard but if the student modify their url to /instructor or /admin ; it will give them access to the page; I want to restrict student to only student page and admin to only admin page.

I tried writing the function

If user.student.is_authenticated:
class Student_dashboard():
......

However it's not restricting them

Comment: Hi there!  Could you add some code, for example your view function and template in order to better show the issue?  Thanks.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [UserPassesTestMixin](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/topics/auth/default/#django.contrib.auth.mixins.UserPassesTestMixin) mixin to add a test function to validate that users have permission to access the view

```
from django.contrib.auth.mixins import UserPassesTestMixin
from django.views import View


class Student_dashboard(UserPassesTestMixin, View):

    def test_func(self):
        return self.request.user.is_student
```